# org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling /META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I'm trying to make a simple JSF (based on PrimeFaces) application run.

The main page is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
        <p:editor />
</body>
</html>
```

When I

1. try to run the web application using `mvn jetty:run` and
2. open the page in the browser,

I get following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error parsing [jar:file:/C:/Users/DP118M/.m2/repository/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.4.1/primefaces-3.4.1.jar!/META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml]:
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:410)
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:431)
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87)
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104)
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:144)
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:95)
        at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)
        at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [jar:file:/C:/Users/DP118M/.
m2/repository/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.4.1/primefaces-3.4.1.jar!/META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml@5,17]
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.error(TagLibraryConfig.java:376)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1621)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1900)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1318)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198)
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:407)
        ... 31 more
```

The code is located at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2012_09_29_primefaces_app.zip .

How can I fix this error?

**Update 1:**

Following the advice of BalusC, I commented out the dependency

```
<dependency>
    groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

in `pom.xml`.

There is no `faces-config.xml` in the code (at least, I can't find it).

When I run the application, I get another error:

```
FATAL: Class com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.classForName(ClassUtils.java:199)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.simpleClassForName(ClassUtils.java:218)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:515)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:487)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureApplication(FacesConfigurator.java:551)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:416)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:338)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:140)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:111)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        ...
```

Where is this FaceletViewHandler used?

Here's the updated code: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2012_09_29_primefaces_app2.zip

**Solution:**

1) Backup the projet.

2) Re-create it in Maven as explained at http://myfaces.apache.org/build-tools/archetypes/myfaces-archetype-helloworld20/index.html by

1. running the command `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://myfaces.apache.org` and
2. selecting `myfaces-archetype-helloworld20` from the list of available options.

3) Add PrimeFaces repository and dependency to `pom.xml`.

Comment: http://eriahit.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/gae-primefaces-spring-maven/ suggests using PrimeFaces 1 to fix this problem. Is this really the ONLY option?

Comment: That's a workaround, not a solution. PrimeFaces 1.x is Facelets 1.x compatible which will obviously work just fine together with a Facelets 1.x view handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presence of `com.sun.facelets.*` in the stacktrace tells that you've the `jsf-facelets` JAR file from Facelets 1.x in your webapp's runtime classpath (and that you have explicitly registered its `ViewHandler` in the webapp's `faces-config.xml`!).

This is not right. Since JSF 2.0, Facelets is already bundled inside the JSF API/impl libraries (which is been moved to `com.sun.faces.facelets.*` package). **Remove** the `jsf-facelets` dependency and its `<view-handler>` from `faces-config.xml`. A clean JSF 2.0 / Facelets setup can be created with *only* the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml` (even *no* context parameters and all other mess) and an empty `faces-config.xml`.

The cause of this exception basically boils down to that Facelets 2.0 compatible tag libraries (like PrimeFaces >=2.0) are not recognized by Facelets 1.x.

When getting started with JSF 2.0, please ensure that you're not looking at JSF 1.x books/resources/examples. Since JSF 2.x, so many things have been changed and are done differently. [Start at our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Comment: See update 1 above. I can't find the place where ViewHandler is used.

Comment: I don't do MyFaces and I'm not in a mood to check its source code structure based on the stacktrace, but I won't be surprised if your particular one is actually a JSF 1.x implementation. PrimeFaces >=2.x is a JSF 2.0 compatible component library, you should then use a JSF 2.0 compatible implementation, which can be either Mojarra 2.x or MyFaces 2.x.

Comment: I took the effort to download your project zip and explore the pom.xml. Again, I don't do Maven, but based on the versions and comments in the pom.xml, it look like that you've got there a JSF 1.2 project setup, not a JSF 2.x one. That would explain the problems you're constantly facing while trying to integrate a JSF 2.0 compatible component library. As said in the answer, please ensure that you're not looking at JSF 1.x books/resources/examples, but instead at JSF 2.x ones. I'd throw away that whole project setup example and start with a new/right one, explicitly targeted for JSF 2.x.

Comment: Thanks, see the "solution" section above.